# Pandas Pivot table for integer column is returning decimal values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm experimenting with pivot tables in python using pandas and I have a column that contains 1s if a word appears in a text and 0s if the word does not appear. Therefore, I'm expecting integer values in the values column, but what I am getting outputs like this:

```
Athens                       0.085366
Atlantic Time (Canada)       0.545455
Baghdad                      0.457746
Baku                         0.500000
Beijing                      0.000000
Belgrade                     0.000000
Berlin                       0.000000
Brasilia                     0.666667
Brisbane                     0.000000
```

I thought it might be taking some ratios instead of totals, but since I am not passing any arguments other than the dataframe and the index and the values, I don't know why it would do that.

I have a dataframe with columns created from JSON code of tweets

```
tweets['timezone'] = list(map(lambda tweet: (tweet['user']['time_zone'] if 'time_zone' != None else None ),tweets_data))
tweets['ktheer'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('كثير', tweet),tweets_data)
```

Those are the two columns I am using for my pivot table and this is the code to make the table:

```
words_pivot = pd.pivot_table(tweets, index = ['timezone'], values = ['ktheer'])
```

Any thoughts about what could be going wrong are greatly appreciated. I have no idea why I wouldn't get integers.

Update: After some playing around, I'm pretty sure that the problem lies with python calculating the pivot values as a ratio of all observations in a given timezone. But I'm still not sure how to fix the problem or what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Because `pandas` is based on `numpy`, you'll probably always get floating point results instead of integers.

The [`pivot_table` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) takes an argument `aggfunc` which defaults to `numpy.mean`. If you change it to `numpy.sum` you should get what you want.

```
words_pivot = pd.pivot_table(tweets, index = ['timezone'], values = ['ktheer'], aggfunc=numpy.sum)
```

Comment: This worked, but I only had to use aggfunc = sum. the numpy was unnecessary. Thanks a lot!